# eval cat inside a function

Tags: bash, shell, eval, cat

I've been trying to evaulate an expression inside a function as follows:

```
eval "fn() { $(cat fn.sh); }"
```

Where *fn.sh* contains the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "You provided $1."
```

So that when I call:

```
fn "a phrase"`
```

it prints "You provided a phrase.". However I cannot get it to work.

What's particularly frustrating is that:

```
eval "$(cat fn.sh)"
```

works perfectly! What am I missing here?

**What I've tried:**

```
eval "fn() { \"\$(cat fn.sh)\"; }"
fn
# bash: #!/bin/sh
# echo "You provided $1."
# return 1: No such file or directory

eval "fn() { \$(cat fn.sh); }"
fn
# bash: #!/bin/sh: No such file or directory
```

and myriad other combinations, most of which at this point is guess work.

Comment: Why aren't you just defining the function in `fn.sh` and simply sourcing it? Using `eval` just opens a security hole for no perceived benefit.

Comment: @chepner The benefit is dynamic function names. If somebody has write access of any sort to these scripts I'll be pretty screwed anyway; they don't take input. Thank you for your concern regarding security however, I acknowledge the flaws of eval

Comment: PS: I know the example does take input, but it is only an example

Comment: Hey @chepner, I found the answer. I'd be very happy if somebody with a bit more experience, such as yourself, could comment explaining or referencing material that explains the security risks associated with `eval`. I don't want to encourage bad practice!

Comment: Side note: the hashbang line in `fn.sh` won't do anything, it'll just be ignored as a comment.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that explicitly Benjamin :)

Comment: Just define a function in the source file, and wrap it in another function or use an alias if you want another name. Don't look for reasons to use `eval`.

Comment: @chepner I disagree with the sentiment from what I've read. I agree `eval` is very dangerous if used poorly, but I think there's no greater risk using `eval` than using any other command when used properly. I think the answers below, especially Benjamin's comment, are well formatted, especially considering my use case is a local script only on a single-user machine. If you could maybe show me a security exploit I'd be happy to acknowledge it.

Comment: Not really, the version from my comment is still vulnerable to injection. If `fn.sh` contains something like `:; } echo "evil command" #` that will declare `fn` as a no-op (containing just `:`) and then run the evil command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
eval "fn() { eval \"\$(cat "fn.sh")\"; }"
```

Mandatory [reference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278427/why-and-when-should-eval-use-be-avoided-in-shell-scripts) that explains to the best degree I understand the security risks of using `eval`.

Comment: Or `eval 'fn() { '"$(< fn.sh)"'; }'`

Comment: I prefer your answer and for its use of single quotes :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `source`/`.` from inside the new function.

```
fn () {
  . fn.sh "$1"
}
```

If the function is used often enough where you think repeated disk I/O would be an issue, the file will almost certainly be in a disk cache when you call `fn`.

Comment: Or make it more dynamic: `f_all() { fx="$1"; shift; source ${fx} "$*"}`