# Is using `eval` to define functions with text from a file evil?

Tags: shell, eval, exploit

This is a follow-up question to [eval cat inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52369629/eval-cat-inside-a-function/52370093#52370093).

---

I'm using `eval` to mimic `import` functionality from other languages (such as JavaScript). This is something I wanted to do on my local machine for a while since I've built up an overwhelming collection of script files.

The reasoning is that I now have a very large number of individual functions in separate files, and I don't want to constantly read files with `source` again and again every time I want to call the functionality.

It's mostly just for fun, but I don't want to shoot my foot off should I ever use it in a less casual context:

```
import_as() { 
  import_name="$1"
  import_fnname="${2:-"$import_name"}"

  if test -f "$1"; then
    echo "File '$1' doesn't exist."
  fi

  case "$2" in 
    *[!-a-zA-Z0-9_]* ) echo "BAD";; 
    *) eval "$2"'() { '"$(< $1.sh)"'; }' ;; 
  esac
}
```

Here's an example of it in use:

***add.sh***

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$(($1 + $2))"
```

***sub.sh***

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$(($1 - $2))"
```

***example_import.sh***

```
import_as "add" "math_add"
import_as "sub"

math_add 2 5       # Returns "7"
math_subtract 5 1  # Returns "4"
```

My question is whether or not this use case of `eval` is vulnerable to exploits after the checks I've performed, or if there is something exploitable in this script?

PS: I understand `eval` is considered evil, and I don't want to hear that as an answer. I want specific reasoning for this use case if you believe that in this use case of `eval` there could be exploits.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I was considering a variable to hold the current `LC_CTYPE` and resetting at the end, but I thought I'd exclude it to keep the code small. Side effects are another matter! Moving the answer now :)

Comment: BTW, I'd also consider `[[:alpha:]]` rather than `[A-Za-z]` -- behavior still can be locale-dependent, but at least it's a bit more reliably so (compared to the wide swings in behavior you get between AaBbCc...Zz and ABC...Zabc...z locales otherwise).

Comment: BTW, I can think of *one* reason to avoid this pattern: The `eval`ed functions won't know which files they came from, so using `PS4=':$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO+'; set -x` to log execution with file and line for each command would be considerably less informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing Charles Duffy's fantastic answer and commentary, this code has been evaluated to be safer:

```
import_as() { 
  # Charles Duffy's suggestions, including side effect reduction.
  current_lc_ctype="$LC_CTYPE" 
  LC_CTYPE=C

  import_name="$1"
  import_fnname="${2:-"$import_name"}"

  case "$import_name" in
    *[!/]*) echo "BAD - local directory only."; return ;;
    *) echo "Okay" ;;
  esac

  if test -f "$import_name"; then
    echo "File '$import_name' doesn't exist."
  fi

  case "$2" in 
    *[!-a-zA-Z0-9_]*) echo "BAD"; return;; 
    *) eval "$2"'() { '"$(< $1.sh)"'; }' ;; 
  esac

  # Change LC_CTYPE back to prior to function call
  LC_CTYPE="$current_lc_ctype"
}
```

Comment: Consider declaring your `local`s to avoid modifying global variables without intent. Setting `local LC_CTYPE=C`, for that matter, may succeed in reverting the change without needing to explicitly set aside the old value.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Excellent consideration! I'll consider the portability trade off, but I am quite sure I agree for my use case :) Thanks for all your help, has been an absolute lesson on security considerations

Comment: Even though `local` is an extension, it's explicitly supported in dash and ash -- perhaps the most widely used otherwise-POSIX-baseline shells. Trying to ensure that your functions `unset` newly-introduced variables otherwise gets messy.

Comment: Thanks again Charles, you're an invaluable source of shell knowledge :)

Comment: BTW, if you're aiming for POSIX compliance, you'll want to change `$(< $1.sh)` to `$(cat -- "$1.sh")`.

Answer (score 1):

**If you trust your arguments to `import_as`** -- both `$1` and `$2`, and the content of the file referenced by `$1` -- the above is safe. `eval` is evil insofar as it permits data to be evaluated as code; if you're hardcoding those contents, they're part of the (trusted) code, not (untrusted) data.

Comment: Just for kicks, what if I don't think that the arguments `$1` and `$2` are safe, but I trust file contents as only local files could be read? i.e., can I write anything that could blow my foot off by accident and then invoke it (so not malicious intent, such as a malicious file)? :)

Comment: Do you mean arguments *to the function from the file*, or arguments *to `import_as`*? It's the latter that are risky.

Comment: I mean the arguments provided to `import_as`, i.e., the function name and the file name, given that they're both checked as above in the function

Comment: That's a locale-specific check, so it's hard to make a firm statement without reviewing every possible character collation order. If you set `LC_CTYPE=C`, so we know exactly what is in `A-Z` and `a-z` ranges, *then* I'd call it safe.

Comment: Haha, oh my good call! How about the first argument, the file contents reference? I presumed that would be the easiest to exploit.

Comment: You trust all local files on your machine? (I mean, web services can often be coerced to write local files, and if they're using `/tmp` or `/uploads` or something...)

Comment: yes, this would not be used for a public server at all. Perhaps if I was to consider its use in a public environment I'd contain the file reference to a single folder and use `case "$1" in *[!/]* ) ... ;; *) echo "Accept" ;; esac`

Comment: *nod* -- only importing code from a specific, trusted directory (where you know and control the write permissions) is definitely a place I would go with this.

Comment: ...as soon as you write code that assumes that nobody but you can ever write *anywhere* on a box, you're opening yourself up to privilege escalations from attackers who've only gotten access to an unprivileged account like `nobody` but are trying to work their way up.